# correct way to get current datetime in php

Tags: php

**Description :**

following is the code I am using to get the current date and time

```
$datetime = (new \DateTime())->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

But the current time it shows and the current time I have has at least a difference of 5 hours and some minutes ... how to solve this problem??

1) How to get the correct current time from the server

2) If time zones are different then how am I supposed to make my website that calculates the time difference between two posts and show when the was the post updated and how many hours or minutes have been passed ??

3) If the post was updated according to USA time then wouldn't it create a problem to be loading those posts in any other different time zone country ..

4) What is the common yet best way to be dealing with getting the current time to save the time of post update or any activity ..??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: yes, it's a timezone issue. you store everything as UTC and convert to a desired timezone at display time.

Answer (score 0):

The server is giving the correct time. Its just set for a different timezone.

To change the timezone just for php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

or if you have access to php.ini

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

For everything you will need to looka t your OS docs for changing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can correct the current timezone via:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'your timezone here');
date_timezone_set("your timezone");
```

If they are different, then convert both times to the same zone and then do the calculation.
You must calculate the difference according to the client's local timezone.